# Request always fail on distant server

Tags: ios, web-services, asihttprequest

I'm using the ASIHTTPRequest for my iOS application. I have to connect to a database through a PHP API (copied below). Here is my function that do the request with ASIHTTPRequest :

```
-(void)startRequest {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:PHP_SCRIPT];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setStringEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:50];
    [request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"getWines"];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

When I run to an API hosted localy with MAMP all works fine. But when I do it by my distant server, my request always fail, with no message.

Here is my API written in PHP, hosted on my distant server :

```
<?php
 function connectToDB(){
     $connexion = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
     return $connexion;
 }

 function getWines($connexion) {
     $req = "SELECT name, category FROM table WHERE prize_50  != 0 OR
                                                            prize_75  != 0 OR
                                                            prize_150 != 0 OR
                                                            prize_300 != 0";

     $res = mysqli_query($connexion, $req);

     echo '[';

     while($current = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        extract($current);
        echo json_encode($current);
     }

     echo ']';

 }

 function getWine($connexion) {

     $name = $_REQUEST["name"];
     $req = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='".$name."'";


     $res = mysqli_query($connexion, $req);
     echo "[";
     echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_assoc($res));
     echo "]";
 }

 $connexion = connectToDB();
 if($connexion) { 
    echo "connected"; 

    if(isset($_REQUEST["getWine"])) {
        getWine($connexion);
    }

    else if(isset($_REQUEST["getWines"])) {
        getWines($connexion);
    }

 }

 else {
     echo "unable to connect to the database";
 }



?>
```

I have no idea what happen, and why it's work on localHost and not on my distant server. If I use the API with a browser like http://myURL/iOS/objc.php?getWines=1 it's work perfectly !

Thank you for helping.

P.S. I have already found a post about make some changes in the code (change the @sythesis for an handwritten getter / setter, but still not working)

Answer (score 0):

Your API looks to be expecting a GET request rather than a POST.  Create your URL with an NSString containing the entire URL and don't set any POST attributes.

Also, you might want to start checking out a replacement for ASI.  It isn't currently being developed and will likely never be ARC compliant.  I switched to AFNetworking and love it.

Comment: If I use the $_POST, why should it wait a GET request? (I'm not really good in PHP, sorry if the question looks like a little "newbe". I have tried to use the AFNNetworking with NSURLRequest, but ASIHTTPRequest looked like easier to use

Comment: I mean if I use the $_REQUEST

Comment: The URL you specified (http://myURL/iOS/objc.php?getWines=1) expects a GET parameter passed in (getWines).  Anytime you see question mark at the beginning of a set of passed in parameters to a URL, that is a GET request.  Also, once you get your mind wrapped about working with Blocks, AFNetworking is far simpler to use and share.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation, but I'm wondering why I get a result with my localhost API and nothing with the distant server?

Comment: Don't know that.  Bottom line is that if you can go to that URL in a browser and get a return, then you should be able to use that exact same URL in the request and don't add any POST parameters and it should work.

Comment: I did it, but still not working, I have no idea what happen, if I use my local server like http://localhost:8888/API/objc.php?getWines=1 it works, but all stuff comming from my distant server does not working, no matter how I do it. And obviously from the localhost all is pretty good